# count of unique occurrences in a dataset that are grouped within cohorts

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

In Excel, I've classified customers into cohorts (mmm-yy), and now with a monthly revenue schedule (250 rows of customer transactions), I'd like to get a unique cohort transaction count across a range of months.  I've been unable to transition from total transactions each month to unique cohort transactions for the month (without including repeat customers).

These are examples of functions I've tried:

I've tried iterations of =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$15=D2,MATCH(B$2:B$15,B$2:B$15,0)),ROW(B$2:B$15)-ROW(B$2)+1),1)) 
This gives me unique members within the cohort

I've also used =COUNTIFS(Worksheet1!$F$2:$F$247,$H2,INDEX(Worksheet1!$H$2:$AQ$247,,MATCH(J$1,Worksheet1!$H$1:$AQ$1,0)),">0")

This only counts the transactions as they occur across the schedule for each cohort, but it does not filter by unique counts.

Assistance is much appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS3ki.jpg

[image: An example data range is first image, and I am trying to get to the image below as the output]

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all at a COUNTUNIQUEIFS?

Comment: I've tried iterations of

=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A$2:A$15=D2,MATCH(B$2:B$15,B$2:B$15,0)),ROW(B$2:B$15)-ROW(B$2)+1),1))

That gives me unique members within the cohort

And I've used 

=COUNTIFS(Worksheet1!$F$2:$F$247,$H2,INDEX(Worksheet1!$H$2:$AQ$247,,MATCH(J$1,Worksheet1!$H$1:$AQ$1,0)),">0")

This only counts the transactions as they occur across the schedule for each cohort, but it does not filter by unique counts.

Comment: You really should have included that in your question; either originally or through an [edit].

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, will keep in mind going forward.

Answer (score 0):

you could also try:

[image]

This is the code below:

```
Public Function CountDiff(valor, referencia)

    'valor = "A"
    'referencia = the range of the month that contains Numbers

    Dim coleccion As New Collection

    For Each celda In referencia

        If Len(celda.Value) > 0 Then

            If IsNumeric(celda.Value) Then

                If Range("b" & celda.Row) = valor Then

                    coleccion.Add Range("c" & celda.Row) & Range("a" & celda.Row) &     Range("b" & celda.Row) & Range("c" & celda.Row)
                End If
            End If
        End If

    Next

    CountDiff = GetUniqueCount(coleccion)

End Function

Private Function GetUniqueCount(aFirstArray)
    Dim arr As Collection
    Set arr = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
        For Each a In aFirstArray

            arr.Add a, CStr(a)
        Next
    On Error GoTo 0
    GetUniqueCount = arr.Count
End Function
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: I really appreciate the VBA-assist, but I was hoping to be able to accomplish this within Excel using formulas.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple Count Unique formula for an Excel worksheet.

```
'unique count of column A
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(A2:A11, A2:A11))
```

You can start with that but you need to add some conditions; e.g. the *Group* column needs to belong to *A* or *B* and the monthly column needs to be non-zero. Change the COUNTIF denominator to a COUNTIFS and add the conditions, change the numerator of the division to logical determination of the same criteria, add the inverse of the numerator to the denominator to avoid #DIV/0! errors.

```
'unique count of column A where Group=G7 and January is non-zero
=SUMPRODUCT((($B$2:$B$999=$G7)*(C$2:C$999>0))/(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$999, $A$2:$A$999, $B$2:$B$999, $G7, C$2:C$999, ">0")+($B$2:$B$999<>$G7)+(C$2:C$999=0)))
```

[image]